# Android Widget: Textview stops marquee on homepage scroll

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I have a text view in my widget that scrolls the text like a marquee. Now, it works in normal state. But, if i scroll(swipe) through my home screen for other pages, then this textview stops scrolling. Any Idea how to solve this?

My xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dip"
    android:background="@drawable/myshape" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="25dp" >

        <requestFocus
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i know this an old question but I'm facing a similar issue. Did u find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your xml looks ok,

in your resume method
try add

```
textview_update.setSelected(true);
```

also, I had found some small devices can't handle textview that has length over 1024 otherwise  it will stop (when memory is full)

Comment: This cannot be done programmatically in a widget. This is virtually done by the `requestfocus` tag in the xml file.

Comment: oh ow  didn't see the word widget above, will check it later